# Canvas drawImage() not working - Javascript game

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

I have been working on a snake game in Javascript using HTML 5 Canvas. The game works with no errors and the image is being loaded by the webpage, however the image is not drawn.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        // get canvas context
        var cvs = $("canvas").get(0);
        var ctx = cvs.getContext("2d");
        // declare variables
        var food;
        var snake;
        var grid = 20;
        var h = cvs.height;
        var w = cvs.width;
        var apple = new Image();

        //Makes the canvas look sharp
        cvs.width *= 2;
        cvs.height *= 2;
        cvs.style.width = cvs.width / 2;
        cvs.style.height = cvs.height / 2;
        ctx.scale(2, 2);

        function init(){

            apple.src = "food.png";

            keyPress();     

            reset();

            setInterval(draw, 1000 / 10);
        }

        function reset(){
            snake = {
                direction: "right",
                x: 0,               
                y: 0,
                length: 5,
                pieces: [],
                score: 0
            };

            food = [];

            addFood();
        }

        function draw() {
            // calls functions and clears squares
            updateSnake();
            moveSnake();
            ctx.clearRect(0, 0, w, h);
            drawFood();
            drawSnake();

            // stores score as a string
            var snakeText = snake.score.toString();
            // add 0's to counter
            while (snakeText.length < 3) {
                snakeText = "0" + snakeText;
            }
            // displays score counter
            ctx.fillStyle = "red";
            ctx.textBaseline= "top";
            ctx.font = "20px monospace";
            ctx.fillText("Score: " + snakeText, 5, 0);
        }

        // draw visible snake
        function drawSnake(){
            ctx.fillStyle = "green";
            ctx.strokeStyle = "black";
            ctx.lineWidth = 1;
            // draw square on snakes head
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.rect(snake.x, snake.y, grid, grid);                 
            ctx.stroke();
            ctx.fill();
            // draws a square on all of the snakes body piecees
            for (var i = 0; i < snake.pieces.length; i++) {
                ctx.beginPath();
                ctx.rect(snake.pieces[i].x, snake.pieces[i].y, grid, grid);
                ctx.stroke();
                ctx.fill();
            }

        }

        function updateSnake(){
            // detects collision with snakes head and body
            for (var i = 0; i < snake.pieces.length; i++) {
                if(snake.x == snake.pieces[i].x && snake.y == snake.pieces[i].y){
                    reset();
                }
            }               

            // get the last element of the food array
            var foodIndex = food.length - 1;

            // go through food array 
            while (foodIndex >= 0) {
                // detects snake collision with food, increase snake length, remove food, increase score
                if(snake.x == food[foodIndex].x && snake.y == food[foodIndex].y){
                    snake.length +=1;
                    food.splice(foodIndex, 1); 
                    snake.score+=1;
                    //add new food
                    addFood();
                }

                // go to the next piece of food
                foodIndex--;
            }

            // clamps down array to length of snake
            snake.pieces.length = Math.min(snake.pieces.length, snake.length - 1);

            // adds the snake pieces to beeginning of array, at the snakes head location
            snake.pieces.unshift({
                x: snake.x,
                y: snake.y
            });
        }

        // generates food in random locations
        function addFood(){

            var valid;
            // generates food if allowed
            while (true) {
                valid = true;

                var newFood = {
                    x: Math.floor(Math.random()*(w / grid)) * grid,
                    y: Math.floor(Math.random()*(h / grid)) * grid
                };
                // stops food being put on the snakes head
                if (snake.x == newFood.x && snake.y == newFood.y) {
                    console.log("head");
                    valid = false;
                }
                // stops food from being put on the sankes body 
                for (var i = 0; i < snake.pieces.length; i++) {
                    if(newFood.x == snake.pieces[i].x && newFood.y == snake.pieces[i].y){
                        console.log("body");
                        valid = false;
                    }
                }
                // stops food from being out on top of each other
                for (var i = 0; i < food.length; i++) {
                    if(newFood.x == food[i].x && newFood.y == food[i].y){
                        valid = false;
                    }
                }
                // add new food to array
                if (valid) {
                    food.push(newFood);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        window.addFood = addFood;

        // draws the visible food
        function drawFood(){
            ctx.fillStyle = "salmon";
            ctx.strokeStyle = "black";
            //Draws at the foods location
            for (var i = 0; i < food.length; i++) {
                ctx.drawImage(apple, food.x, food.y, grid, grid);
            }
        }

        function moveSnake(){

            if(snake.direction == "right"){
                snake.x+= grid;
            }
            if(snake.direction == "left"){
                snake.x-= grid;
            }
            if(snake.direction == "up"){
                snake.y-= grid;
            }
            if(snake.direction == "down"){
                snake.y+= grid;
            }

            if(snake.x < 0){
                reset();
            }
            if(snake.x > w-20){
                reset();
            }
            if(snake.y > h-20){
                reset();
            }   
            if(snake.y < 0){
                reset();
            }           
        }
        // detects keys pressed
        function keyPress(){

            $(document).keydown(function(e){

                if(e.keyCode == 37 && snake.direction != "right"){
                    snake.direction = "left";
                }
                if(e.keyCode == 39 && snake.direction != "left"){
                    snake.direction = "right";
                }
                if(e.keyCode == 38 && snake.direction != "down"){
                    snake.direction = "up";
                }
                if(e.keyCode == 40 && snake.direction != "up"){
                    snake.direction = "down";
                }

            })
        }

        init();
    });

</script>
```

```
<canvas width="400" height="400" style="border: solid black 1px">
    Sorry, no canvas support!
</canvas>
```

The image is created in the variablees and given a source in my init() function:

```
        var cvs = $("canvas").get(0);
        var ctx = cvs.getContext("2d");
        // declare variables
        var food;
        var snake;
        var grid = 20;
        var h = cvs.height;
        var w = cvs.width;
        var apple = new Image();

        //Makes the canvas look sharp
        cvs.width *= 2;
        cvs.height *= 2;
        cvs.style.width = cvs.width / 2;
        cvs.style.height = cvs.height / 2;
        ctx.scale(2, 2);

        function init(){

            apple.src = "food.png";

            keyPress();     

            reset();

            setInterval(draw, 1000 / 10);
        }
```

drawImage() is called here in the drawFood() function:

```
function drawFood(){
            ctx.fillStyle = "salmon";
            ctx.strokeStyle = "black";
            //Draws at the foods location
            for (var i = 0; i < food.length; i++) {
                ctx.drawImage(apple, food.x, food.y, grid, grid);
            }
        }
```

I have tried using an onLoad function / EventListeners but cannot get it to work.

Thanks.

Comment: You need to wait for the image to load by checking `image.complete === true` before you try to draw it. Or use the image `onload` event to start the rendering process.

Comment: @Blindman67 Have tried both of these methods but still cant seem to get it working

Comment: Do you have a fiddle or some such working example. A quick look at your code and i can see no obvious fault. Check the devTools console as it will show if the image failed to load due to error (bad url, bad file, etc...)

Comment: @Blindman67 Ok i tried running it through jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/cb5a9pb2/1/ and through jsbin, the console showed an error saying that my drawImage function is in a broken state, this error doesn't show up when you run it normally in thee browser

Comment: Fiddle cant find the apple image, as you are trying to load it from the fiddle domain. But found your problem change `ctx.drawImage(apple,food[i].x,food[i].y,grid,grid);` you just forgot to index into the food array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in the draw food function

```
    function drawFood(){
        ctx.fillStyle = "salmon";
        ctx.strokeStyle = "black";
        //Draws at the foods location
        for (var i = 0; i < food.length; i++) {
            // you had ctx.drawImage(apple, food.x, food.y, grid, grid);
            // should be
            ctx.drawImage(apple, food[i].x, food[i].y, grid, grid);
        }
    }
```

But you should still check images have loaded before you try to draw them. There are plenty of examples of how to load images here on stackoverflow.

Comment: Thanks a lot that fixed it, it's always something simple :)